# Linking Static Library with Dynamic Library Error : LNK2038 Mismatch detected

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015, static-libraries

I am new to the Windows environment and I am trying to build a DLL project in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. The DLL project depends on some libraries, DLLs as well as static (BeJsonCpp.lib)

When I try to compile the project, I get the

> LNK2038

The description is as follows

```
mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' dosen't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in .obj
```

I tried to compile the project with /MD (MD_DynamicRelease) Code Generation Option, as well as with /MDd (MDd_DynamicDebug) option, but the error persists.

If I change the project configuration type from Dynamic Library (.dll) to Static Library (.lib) I could compile and link the project successfully without any errors. But compiling it as a Dynamic Library throws the above error.

What I think is that BeJsonCpp is built for static environment and hence it is showing this behavior.

I want the output to be DLL.

I do not have the source of BeJsonCpp Library.

Comment: The problem is you are mixing debug and release. If you don't have a debug binary for the dependent library then you can't build a debug executable for your application.

Comment: I think this was the problem. Selected release and it compiled. Thank you @drescherjm